# Different Print Styles to encapsulated Web Components

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, web-component

I have two HTML files that have the same content but different styling. One uses Bootstrap 4 and the other uses Bootstrap 5, both files contain a Web Component with an encapsulated style and the CSS :host property set to all: initial.

When viewing both pages normally and with the print stylesheet emulation in Firefox and Chrome, they appear the same. However, when I try to print them, the text size on one of the pages changes. I can't figure out what could be affecting the text inside the component under the assumption of style encapsulation and :host all: initial.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Bootstrap 5 Version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    @page {
        size: a4 !important;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body onload="window.print()">
    <script>const templateHeadereearo = document.createElement('template');
templateHeadereearo.innerHTML = `<style>* { box-sizing: border-box; } :host {all: initial; display: block;} .headertest {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1cm;
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 1cm;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
}</style><div class="headertest">
    This is a test
</div>`
class Headereearo extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(templateHeadereearo.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
window.customElements.define('headereearo-', Headereearo)
</script><headereearo-></headereearo->
</body>
</html>
```

Bootstrap 4 Version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    @page {
        size: a4 !important;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body onload="window.print()">
    <script>const templateHeaderpagni = document.createElement('template');
templateHeaderpagni.innerHTML = `<style>* { box-sizing: border-box; } :host {all: initial; display: block;} .headertest {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1cm;
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 1cm;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
}</style><div class="headertest">
    This is a test
</div>`
class Headerpagni extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(templateHeaderpagni.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
window.customElements.define('headerpagni-', Headerpagni)
</script><headerpagni-></headerpagni->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Even with:
all: initial !important

Edit:
Added Screenshots of both Versions in Print Preview, where you can see that the containing DIV has a different height and the Text has other Size Propertys.

[Bootstrap 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDiuQ.png)
[Bootstrap 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoTOZ.png)

Comment: Could you leave a very small screenshot to showcase what's happening and highlight the parts that are effectivelly behaving differently? HTML/CSS support vary a lot from browser to browser and bootstrap might have different workaround between v4 and 5 creating the issue. Is it ugly/blocking ? (That's why screenshot would help)

Comment: Sure added screenshots as a edit!

Comment: Can you try writing a css for the print media? I think that is the problem here. Try use @media print for the css.

Comment: It's not about my custom CSS, it's about some sort of CSS leaking through the View Encapsulation inside the WebComponent. Which should as far as I am aware not happen.
After further testing I can now say for sure, that the Bootstrap 4 Version has some Issues, because a new Version without any Style Frameworks looks exactly like the Bootstrap 5 Version.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so for anyone encountering the same issue. It looks like the View Encapsulation was working. The only thing which causing the Issue was:

```css
@media print {
  body {
    min-width: 992px !important;
  }
}
```

Inside Bootstrap 4 at the Bottom. So a simple override:

```css
body {
  min-width: 0 !important;
}
```

Would do the trick! Thanks to everyone!